# The radius of convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Given the following series: $\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{x}{\sin n}\right)^{n}$

How to find the radius of convergence?

I tried to use Cauchy–Hadamard theorem and got

$R^{-1} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left|\frac{x}{\sin n}\right|$

What should I do next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|x|}{|\sin n|}$ does not exist. However, $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{|x|}{|\sin n|}=+\infty$, since $\liminf_{n\to\infty}|\sin n|=0$. Therefore, the radius of convergence of your series is $0$.